# Why does my program outputs some weird symbols?

Tags: c

I want to make a program which dynamically allocate 2D array and then add random numbers to it. But for some reason it just outputs some weird symbols.

So what did I do wrong? Here's my code:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int** allocateArray(int** array_, int row, int col) {
    array_ = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*) * row);
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
        array_[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * col);
    return array_;
}

int** addRandomNumbers(int** array_,int row,int col) {
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for(int j=0;j<col;j++){
            array_[i][j] = rand() % 10;
        }
    }
    return array_;
}
void print(int** array_, int row, int col) {
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
            printf("%d ", array_[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
int main() {
    int** array_ = NULL;
    int row = 5;
    int col = 5;

    array_ = allocateArray(array_, row, col);
    array_ = addRandomNumbers(array_, row, col);

    printf(array_,row,col);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't just `printf(array_,row,col);`. You need two loops to print `array_[i][j]` using the `%d` format specifier

Comment: Adding to above comments: It is currently printing the memory address that the array is pointing to

Comment: In `allocateArray` why do you pass `array_` since you return the allocated memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`printf(array_,row,col);` is wrong. You want  `print(array_,row,col);`

`int** allocateArray(int** array_, int row, int col)` parameter `array_` is not needed at all. If you want to modify the pointer itself you need to `int** allocateArray(int*** array_, int row, int col)`

Do `srand` only once in the program.

Use `size_t` type (not `int`) for sizes.

I would use pointer to array myself:

```
void *allocateArray(size_t row, size_t col) 
{
    int (*array)[col] = malloc(sizeof(*array) * row);
    return array;
}

void *addRandomNumbers(void *array,size_t row,size_t col) 
{
    int (*arr)[col] = array;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for(size_t j=0; j < col; j++){
            arr[i][j] = rand() % 10;
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
void print(void *array, size_t row, size_t col) 
{
    int (*arr)[col] = array;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < col; j++) {
            printf("%d ", arr[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
int main() {
    size_t row = 5;
    size_t col = 5;
    int (*array)[col];
    
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));

    array = allocateArray(row, col);
    array = addRandomNumbers(array, row, col);

    print(array,row,col);
    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/qn4YeMcxn

I would personally